# Display action bar in few activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar

I created a custom theme style with no action bar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And in my manifest I use this style:

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

That way there is no action bar in all of my activites. However I would like it to appear in just certain activities. I tried to add the code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_edit_profile, null)

    setContentView(view)
    supportActionBar?.show()
```

But the action bar is not showing and I assume the reason is that the theme doesn't support an action bar. I would only like to display the action bar in few activities, even so should I create a theme with an action bar and hide it programatically in most of the activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create style with action bar

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

then create another style with no action bar

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

then use like this

**activities with action bar**

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:label="MyActivity"></activity>
```

**activities with no action bar**

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:label="MyActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create theme for With `ActionBar`

```
<style name="AppActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

You Already  have theme `AppTheme` for no Actionbar .

Add this theme to your Activity in `Manifest` file just like this

For NoActionBar

```
  <activity android:name=".NoActionBarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="NoActionBarActivity"></activity>
```

For ActionBar

```
  <activity android:name=".ActionBarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppActionBarTheme"
        android:label="ActionBarActivity"></activity>
```

For whole Application .Just add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` line  in Application tag .Just like this

```
  <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

Or hide/show `ActionBar` programmatically  just like this

```
  //to show ActionBar
  supportActionBar?.show()

 //to hide ActionBar
  supportActionBar?.hide()
```